# Black bar on top and bottom of screen in Samsung Galaxy S 8

Tags: unity-game-engine, aspect-ratio, samsung-galaxy

My game, developed with Unity, runs in portrait and full-screen mode. There is no problem in any device except Samsung Galaxy S8, in which the full-screen mode doesn't exactly work and as you can see in the attached picture, there are black bars on the top and bottom of the screen (assume the white part is the game area). Funny part is there is absolutely no problem in S8+, which I believe has the same exact aspect ratio (18.5:9). What should I do? I am using Unity 5.6.6 and can't upgrade it.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Add (and familiarize yourself with) a CanvasScaler component to your Canvas.

Comment: Thank you very much, @zambari. My canvas already has this component. These are the attributes:

- UI Scale Mode: Scale With Screen Size
- Reference Resolution: 1080*1920
- Screen Match Mode: Match Width or Height
- Math: 1
- Reference Pixel Per Unit: 100. What else do you think I should do?

Comment: Screen with screensize will try to match source proportions, try using the other two options